# Repeated elements in an ArrayList (java)

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to get the count of the most frequently occurring  element in an arrayList of Objects. I have this code and it´s working.

```
public static int contarRepeditos(ArrayList<Objecto> a) {
    int resul = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> valores = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        valores.add(a.get(i).getValor());
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> resultados = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < valores.size(); i++) {
        resultados.add(Collections.frequency(valores, a.get(i).getValor()));
    }
    resul = Collections.max(resultados);
    return resul;
}
```

I need to know if there are a best way to do that. Thanks.

Comment: Your code doesn't match your description. It sounds like you need to get the count of the most frequently occurring value of `valor` - is that the case?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's difficult to me express this in English. Is the most frequently. for example 5 Objects with (0) (0) (0) (1) (1). You get 3.

Answer (score 5):

The typical method would be to use a map, where the key would be the "valor" value, and the value would be a running count of how many times that value has appeared.

Answer (score 1):

Example using map:

```
public static int contarRepeditos(List<Objecto> a) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> freqMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (Objecto obj : a) {
        freqMap.put(obj.getValor(), (freqMap.get(obj.getValor()) == null ? 1 : (freqMap.get(obj.getValor()) + 1)));
    }
    return Collections.max(freqMap.values());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bhesh. That's look much better.